# Finding the position of all instances of a word in a string, getting unwanted repetition in console

Tags: javascript, str-replace

So I'm trying to create a simple function that finds the position of all instances of a word in any given string without using a for loop, regular expressions, or converting the string into an array, though I'd be interested in seeing those solutions too.

The code:

```
function wordFinder(word, text) {
   var findStart = text.search(word);
   var total = findStart  + ' to ' + (findStart += word.length);
   console.log(total);  
   text = text.replace(word[0], ' '); 
     if(text.search(word) == -1) { 
       console.log("all done");
       } else { 
              return wordFinder(word, text);
        }
};

wordFinder("hello", "hijellohellohello");
```

I would expect the console to show

```
"7 to 12"
"12 to 17"
"all done"
```

But instead I get

```
"7 to 12"
"7 to 12"
"12 to 17"
"all done"
```

Having played with it some, it's clear that if a character which matches word[0] comes *before* the word it causes the console.log(total) to fire once for each match, but I'm not sure why it's doing this.

Edit: explanation makes sense, and here's my ugly solution that uses a for loop and creates a questionable situation with undefined, but it works! If anyone wants to tell me how it would actually be done in a real environment, that'd be appreciated.

```
    function wordFinder(word, text) {
    var findStart = text.search(word);
    var total = findStart  + ' to ' + (findStart += word.length); 

var holder = [];
var spacer = " ";
  console.log(total); 
for(i=0; i + 1 < word.length; i++) {
  holder.push(spacer[i]);
      if(holder[i] === undefined) {
      holder[i] = spacer;
      }
} 
  text = text.replace(word, holder);
       if(text.search(word) == -1) { 
        console.log("all done");
       } else {
    return wordFinder(word, text);
     }
}
wordFinder("abc", "abaabczabcabc");
```

returns

```
"3 to 6"
"7 to 10"
"10 to 13"
"all done"
```

Comment: Actually `text.search` *is* a regex method?

Comment: You should first check your base case, then call the recursion. Currently your function doesn't work on strings that contain no occurence of the word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're taking the first letter and replacing it with a space. So your starting text is `hijellohellohello` the first time, and `ijellohellohello` the second time which means that your first instance of hello is still in the same spot. So when you run the recursion the second time around, you get the same result.

Edit: To clarify further, the beginning of the text begins with "h". If `word` begins with "h" and you do `word[0]` that will be equal to "h". You're saying replace the first instance of "h" with a space. So it prints out "7 to 12", does the replace, prints it out again, then does another replace, then finds the last instance of "hello"

Comment: Made edits per your answer not sure if there's a way to get around using a for loop without totally scrapping it and starting over. Thanks!

Comment: I think using the for loop works fine. It could be cleaned up slightly, but looks like it works. Make it work, then make it better! :)